# ¿Como Exportar dos datagriview de visual a excel en diversas hojas?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Espero puedan ayudarme, quiero exportar dos **datagridview** a un libro de **excel**, un datagridview por hoja, pero no sé como ya lo intenté pero me sale error, éste es mi codigo, pero solo es para un datagriview en una hoja de un libro.

El método es éste:

```
         Public Sub ExportarExcel(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal pth As String)
            Try
                Dim xlApp As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                'crea una nueva hoja
                Dim xlWB As Object = xlApp.Workbooks.add
                Dim xlWS As Object = xlWB.Worksheets(1)


                'exportamos caracteres de las columnas
                For c As Integer = 0 To TABLAFINAL.Columns.Count - 1
                    xlWS.cells(1, c + 1).value = TABLAFINAL.Columns(c).HeaderText
                    xlWS.cells(1, c + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(46, 134, 193)
                Next
                'exportamos las cabeceras de las columna
                For r As Integer = 0 To TABLAFINAL.RowCount - 1
                    For c As Integer = 0 To TABLAFINAL.Columns.Count - 1
                        xlWS.cells(r + 2, c + 1).value = TABLAFINAL.Item(c,r).Value
                    Next
                Next


                'guardamos la hoja de calculo
                xlWB.saveas(pth)
                xlWS = Nothing
                xlWB = Nothing
                xlApp.quit()
                xlApp = Nothing
                MessageBox.Show("Documento Exportado Correctamente")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error al Exportar documento")
            End Try
        End Sub
```

y lo mando llamar con un botón

```
     Private Sub BTNEXPORTAR_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNEXPORTAR.Click
            Try
                Dim save As New SaveFileDialog
                save.Filter = "Archivo Excel | *.xlsx"
                If save.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    ExportarExcel(Me.TABLAFINAL, save.FileName)
                End If
                Me.BTNEXPORTAR.Enabled = False
                BTNCALCULAR.Enabled = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Como puedo agregar una nueva hoja, y exportarla a otro datagriview.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión estas mandando en la llamada a `ExportarExcel` el parámetro `Me.TABLAFINAL` el cual es recogido por `dgv`. Pero dentro del código usas `TABLAFINAL` en vez de usar `dgv`, para acceder a los datos del `DataGrindView`

También cuando asignas la 
`Worksheet` a

`xLWS Dim xlWS As Object = xlWB.Worksheets(1)`

el índice creo que debe ser `0` si solo hay una `Worksheet`.